# Java/Tomcat 7 can't get local stylesheets to work

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm new to java development and I've started playing around using Eclipse and Tomcat 7 to create some simple pages and get more used to it but I've run into a bit of a weird issue.

I've created a simple "Hello World" jsp page, that in the head has a reference to a stylesheet using a `<link>` tag e.g `<link href="style.css" />` .The path is correct, and even if I try it with a fully qualified path it doesn't work. If I link to an external stylesheet it does show however. I've looked around and the main suggestion I can find is adding a servlet-mapping with a name of default to *.css in my web.xml . I have done this but this still doesn't appear to work. Using `<style>` tags with an @import statement does work and is a workaround for now. But I'm a bit mythed as to what's going on here.

Due to the fact that external stylesheets work I can only assume this is down to a config setting in Tomcat but for the life of me I can't find what I need to change.

As I'm quite new to all this I'm not sure what's really going on. I assume the web.xml is similar to a web.config/.htaccess and there must be a setting in there causing this to fail. Other then the aforementioned change I haven't adjusted anything so it should all be default settings, which seems extremely bizarre to me. I've had a look around for some beginners tutorials on the web but unfortunately haven't come across much.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT

The stylesheet is in the webcontent folder, so in exactly the same directory as the index.jsp . If i put the address of the stylesheet into the address bar it does show correctly. The contents of the index.jsp file are as follows:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Index JSP</title>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" /> <!-- This doesn't work -->
<style>
@import url(style.css); <!-- This does work -->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello World</p>
</body>
</html>
```

my web.xml in the WEB-INF directory has the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

<display-name>test</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the contents of your web.xml as well as the path of the style.css file relative to your project? Did you try to manually access the css from the browser?

Comment: Can you specify where the css files are located. Are they visible to public or are they present with in the WEB-INF folder? As a norm static resources should be outside WEB-INF. Pasting the actual jsp content helps